# How can I access the object that is a reference to another object in Firebase

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, reference

My Firebase .json looks like:

```js
"Employees": {
    "Employee1" : {
      "Activities": {
        "Activity1": true
      },
      "age" : 61,
      "name" : "Employee1"
     },
     .
     .
     .
    //other employees
}
"Activities": {
     "Activity1": {
       "name": "Name of Activity1",
       "value": 2,
       "cost": 2
     },
     .
     .
     .
     //other activities
}
```

What I want to do is to display Employee1. In this case, Employee1 has only Activity1 under Activities. I need to display Employee1 data, including data of its Activities. I am working with React and I am using 
`firebase.database().ref()` and `on('value', function(snapshot))` to display data from Firebase. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In NoSQL data modelling, you should not hesitate to duplicate data, i.e. to denormalize in such a way it makes your queries easier and, more important, faster.

So, in your case, you could modify your data stucture as follows:

```
"Employees": {
    "Employee1" : {
      "Activities": {
        "Activity1": {
          "name": "Name of Activity1",  // <- add the details of the activity here
          "value": 2,
          "cost": 2
         },
      },
      "age" : 61,
      "name" : "Employee1"
     },
     .
     .
     .
    //other employees
}
"Activities": {
     "Activity1": {
       "name": "Name of Activity1",
       "value": 2,
       "cost": 2
     },
```

One drawback of this technique is that you have to maintain the two nodes in sync, but this can easily be done by using the `update()` method, see the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#update_specific_fields)

Comment: @nedzadhafizovic Happy that I coud help you. You may accept the answer, by clicking the grey checkmark on the left of the answer, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer. Thanks